# Green Sock GSAP TweenMax, settle on last frame

Tags: gsap

I have an animated spritesheet which uses the following code:

```
 TweenMax.to(".globe__globe", 5, { backgroundPosition:'0 -67280px', ease:SteppedEase.config(145)});
```

This means that over 5 seconds, the background position will be animated. The SteppedEase function defines that there are 145 frames. This works as expected, but at the end of the animation is simply resets back to the first frame. I need it to end on the last frame. Help?

Comment: Possible to create a fiddle or a codepen demo of this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out frames are zero-indexed so if I knocked one frames-worth height off the background position and reduced frames to 145, this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant change it to 144 frames. 
So the final code would be

```
TweenMax.to(".globe__globe", 5, 
    { backgroundPosition:'0 -67280px', ease:SteppedEase.config(144)});
```